# on mouse hover save image temporarily in localstorage and send to server via AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

When I hover my mouse over an image ,the image should be saved temporarily in "localStorage" with the help of javascript.Then it should be send to server via AJAX.

there are 2 ques.
1) how to save the image on the localStorage when the mouseover on it.
2) how to send the image from localstorage to server.

sorry for not being clear abt the question at  first.

Comment: mouseover functions in javascript . in which i couldnt find to store the data temporarily in  localstorage

Comment: @user2044000 why you un-tick answer??

Comment: please go through the ques. once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save your data in localstorage by

```
// Store your data.
function saveStuff(obj) {
  saveData.obj = obj;
  saveData.time = new Date().getTime();
  localStorage.saveData = JSON.stringify(saveData);
}

// Do something with your data.
function loadStuff() {
  return saveData.obj || "default";
}
```

and after that 
with

```
var saveData = JSON.parse(localStorage.saveData || null) || {//you can write your code to save to server};
```

hope this can help :)